# OpenSSL compiles for wrong target

Tags: android-ndk, openssl, cross-compiling

I'm trying to build FIPS compliant OpenSSL for android (4.1.2 if it matters) and I've got a problem.

I've been following the steps from http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_Library_and_Android#OpenSSL_FIPS_Components and this is what happens:

```
$ export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk/
$ export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/opt/android-ndk-r9b/
$ export FIPS_SIG /home/<username>/work/openssl/openssl-fips-2.0.5/util/incore

$ ./setenv-android.sh

$ cd openssl-fips-2.0.5/
$ ./config
$ make

$ readelf -h ./fips/fipscanister.o | grep -i 'class\|machine'
  Class:                             ELF64
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
```

I believe this class and machine should be ELF32 and ARM as per the instructions. I've somehow built for the box I'm working on not for android. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference a dot makes:

```
./setenv-android.sh
```

is incorrect and needs to be

```
. ./setenv-android.sh
```

The difference is that the first sets up the environment variables for the script process - which then exits losing everything. The second sets it all up in the same process that ran the script which is the desired outcome.